# $.each function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eventually I'm trying to create a timed slide show that fades images in and out. What I can't figure out is why my $.each function does complete the loop for each index of the array and instead only loops the last image seven times.

Here is my code...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var image1 = "<img width='600' height='400' src='images/image1.jpg' />";
    var image2 = "<img width='600' height='400' src='images/image2.jpg' />";
    var image3 = "<img width='600' height='400' src='images/image3.jpg' />";
    var image4 = "<img width='600' height='400' src='images/image4.jpg' />";
    var image5 = "<img width='600' height='400' src='images/image5.jpg' />";
    var image6 = "<img width='600' height='400' src='images/image6.jpg' />";
    var image7 = "<img width='600' height='400' src='images/image7.jpg' />";
    var image8 = "<img width='600' height='400' src='images/image8.jpg' />";

    var imageArray = new Array(image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8);
    $.each(imageArray, function(key, value){
        $('#slide').html(value);
        $('#slide').hide().fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

Again, what ends up happening is that the last image fades in and out 7 times before disappearing. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Can you debug and see what is passed to the handler function in each iteration?

Comment: When I do something as such...

Comment: omg, haha

`$.each(imageArray, function(key, value){
        alert(value);
        $('#slide').html(value);
        $('#slide').hide().fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow');
    });`

it alerts the value as intended.

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/6CS4A/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that JavaScript execution doesn’t pause whilst `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are doing their thing.

Your  `each` call does this:

1. Sets the HTML of `#slide` to `image1`.
2. Hides `#slide`.
3. Starts fading in `#slide`.
4. Immediately sets the HTML of `#slide` to `image2` (because it doesn’t wait for `fadeIn` to finish), overwriting `image1`.
5. Starts fading in `#slide` again.

And so on.

In order to get the outcome you want, you’ll need a recursive function (i.e. a function that calls itself) instead of your `each` call. This function will need to pass callback functions to `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` — these functions will get called when `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` have finished executing.

E.g.

```
function fadeImagesInAndOut(imageArray, imageIndex) {
    $('#slide').html( imageArray(imageIndex) );

    $('#slide').hide().fadeIn('slow', function () {

        $('#slide').fadeOut('slow', function () {

            if (imageIndex < imageArray.length) {
                fadeImagesInAndOut(imageArray, imageIndex + 1);
            }
        });
    });
}

fadeImagesInAndOut(imageArray, 0);
```

Comment: beautiful, thanks guys, all of you. I recall what a recursive function is. I'll have to commit this use of it to memory >.<

Answer (score 2):

That is because your loop doen't wait for the animation to be completed. It keeps all the animation commands in queue one after the other. So better give a callback to check when the animation is completed  and then change the image(by continuing the loop).
Else you gotta do like Thilo suggested

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the $('#slide') html 8 times, rewriting it each time. Probably you intend to append  each image to it?

```
$('#slide').append( $(value) );
```

Also, you are calling hide() on #slide 8 times. Is this what you intend?

EDIT: not tested, but gives you an idea of how to use callback

```
var imgArray = new Array(...)

var doAnimate = function(key){
   if(!value = imgArray[key]) return;
   $('#slide').html(value);
   $('#slide').hide().fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow', function(){
       doAnimate(key++);
   });
}

doAnimate(0);
```

Comment: He does not wants to append all the images but move from one to another like an animation.

Comment: I changed my
`$('#slide')`
to
`$('#slide img')`

which is what I initially had, just messed it up while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The magic of asynchronous execution.

Chronological sequence of events:

```
    $('#slide').html(image1);
    $('#slide').hide();
    #   fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow'); will happen some time later
    $('#slide').html(image2);
    $('#slide').hide();
    #   fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow'); will happen some time later
    $('#slide').html(image3);
    $('#slide').hide();
    #   fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow'); will happen some time later
```

The loop will enter the second (and third and so on) iteration, resetting the image until it is the last one, before the first animation is finished.

Comment: why does it do this? Still confused a bit.

Comment: fadeIn() takes time. But the script does not wait for it to complete. The loop just goes on, while the animations are all queued up and executed in the background.

Comment: Thanks man, much appreciated; I get it now... I'll have to remember that.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is animation is executed asynchronously. The order of executing commands in your code is:

1. Set `$('#slide').html` to 1st image.
2. Ask jQuery to start animation of the object. Animation is not started yet.
3. Set `$('#slide').html` to 2st image.
4. Ask for another animation.
5. ...
6. Ask for an animation the last time.
7. Your function is complete. Browser starts redrawing the page and firing timeout events. Your container is hidden, its html refers to the last image.
8. jQuery animates your container.

You need to change html of the container only after animation ends. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //populate imageArray 
  function animate_one(index) {
    if (index >= imageArray.length) return;
    $('#slide').html(imageArray[index]);
    $('#slide').hide().fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      animate_one(index+1);
    });
  }
  animate_one(0);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ytVK/)

Answer (score 0):

A way how to do it (with a nice fade effect):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ujecel/2/edit)*

Put one image inside a DIV, than just loop the array **prepending** a new image into the DIV. Fade out the old image (and remove) using `:last` selector.

```
var images = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg'];       // your images
                                                              
var c = 0;                                                   // set the first image
$('#slide').prepend( '<img src="'+ images[c] +'" />' );      // prepend one

function loop(){ 
    $('#slide').prepend( '<img src="'+ images[c++ % images.length] +'" />' );    
       $('#slide img:last').delay(1000).fadeTo(700,0,function(){
            $(this).remove();                                // remove last one
            loop();
       });  
}
loop();
```

In your css make sure your images are absolutely positioned.